# Api platform 3 Symfony 6 Custom Property Filter

Tags: symfony, filter, api-platform.com, symfony6

I've added the propertyFilter to filter by property, but It does not match with a format I want .... actually it is: properties[]=field1&properties[]=field2 ... I want to have it like properties=field1,field2,....

I've tried to set up an event listener on kernel_request (pre-read priority) to make some conversion but it does not work because the uri is already generated.

How can I achieve it plz?

### **Edit**

I'd like to implement a solution in the context of ApiPlatform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fount a way to make it work in the context of api platform and entities, I've create a serialize contextbuilder documented here https://api-platform.com/docs/core/serialization/#changing-the-serialization-context-dynamically (the example of Book) and I change the attributes in the function createFromRequest:

```
public function createFromRequest(Request $request, bool $normalization, ?array $extractedAttributes = null): array
{
    $context = $this->decorated->createFromRequest($request, $normalization, $extractedAttributes);
    if (!empty($request->query->get('properties'))) {
        $fields = explode(',', $request->query->get('properties'));
        $context['attributes'] = array_values($properties);
    }
    
    return $context;
}
```